# Python бот для бесконечного прохождения игры

Tags: python, бот, google-play-games

Реально ли реалезовать подобное https://youtu.be/8nUqQBXnTTA на python? И какие инструменты для этого потребуются?

Comment: На какой платформе игра? Как вообще называется?

Comment: Android, subway surfers